# VHDL shift operators?

Tags: vhdl

I'm still trying to get used to some of the quirks of VHDL and I'm having a bit of an issue. First off, I understand that shift operators like rol, ror, ssl, srl, etc. are not synthesizeable. The purpose of this lab is to use a golden model to check against a synthesizeable version of the same thing in a testbench.

Now, the purpose of this program is to convert thermometer code into a 3-bit binary number. So, in other words, thermometer code "00000001" = "001", "00000011" = "010", "00000111" = "011", etc. I'm basically trying to count the number of 1's in the string from right to left. There will be no case where a '0' is placed between the string of 1's, so the vector "00011101" is invalid and will never occur.

I've devised a non-synthesizeable (and so far, non-compile-able) algorithm that I can't figure out how to get working. Basically, the idea is to read the thermometer code, shift it right and increment a counter until the thermometer code equals zero, and then assign the counter value to the 3-bit std_logic_vector. Below is the code I've done so-far.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all; 
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity therm2bin_g is
    port(therm : inout std_logic_vector(6 downto 0); -- thermometer code
         bin : out std_logic_vector(2 downto 0); -- binary code 
         i : integer range 0 to 7);
end therm2bin_g;    

architecture behavioral_g of therm2bin_g is
begin

golden : process(therm)
begin

    while(therm /= "00000000") loop
        therm <= therm srl 1;
        i = i + 1;      
    end loop;

    bin <= std_logic'(to_unsigned(i,3));

end process golden;
behavioral_g;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a few little syntactic problems with this code but overall it's not far off and it'll be a useful way into distinguishing between synthesisable and non-synthesisable - which really isn't what you are expecting!

1) The port map

```
port(therm : inout std_logic_vector(6 downto 0); -- thermometer code
     bin : out std_logic_vector(2 downto 0); -- binary code 
     i : integer range 0 to 7);
```

Points to note here:

1. `therm` and `bin` have both a mode and a type; `i` has only a type. As `bin` is only a copy of `i` you don't really need both in the port list. You can declare `i` internally as a signal, or even in the process as a variable.
2. `bin` represents an Unsigned number. So good style is to make it Unsigned; or even Integer, and convey more of the design intent to the reader. Both of these are perfectly synthesizable. Integer may give you a 32-bit integer, so make it `bin : out natural range 0 to 7;` and you will get a 3 bit unsigned integer! The lesson here is that if you're doing lots of unnecessary type conversions, STOP: think, and you will find a way to **use** the type system instead of **fight** it.
3. `therm` has been declared "`inout`" but it is really an input to the process. (The fact that you are modifying it internally is an implementation detail, you REALLY don't want to expose the modified version to the outside world!) In fact, "`inout`" really doesn't do what you think it does. Its real purpose is only for data buses and similar, where you communicate both ways on the same signal. If you use it as you are, then whatever drives the original value on `therm` will still drive `therm`, and your modified values will conflict with that to produce "`X`", i.e. unknown value (Or in real hardware, possibly overheat and burn out!).

So eliminate `i`, make `bin` Unsigned or a subtype of Natural, and make `therm` an input.

2) You need a local copy of `therm` you can modify. Declare it locally as a signal.

```
architecture behavioral_g of therm2bin_g is
   therm_int : std_logic_vector(6 downto 0);
begin
```

And `i` needs to be declared locally too. It could be a signal too, but let's make it a variable in the process instead.

```
golden : process(therm)
variable i : integer := 0;
-- yes, it is important to initialise it!
begin
```

3) The loop.

First we need to copy the input into the internal signal, then we can modify it in the loop.

```
therm_int <= therm;
while (therm_int /= "00000000") loop
    therm_int <= therm_int srl 1;
    i := i + 1;      
end loop;
```

To simplify it, you could make therm_int unsigned, and write  `while therm_int /= 0 loop` (losing the silly C-style parentheses in the process)

There is another problem here. Think of a process as like a little program in C (but without some of C's stupider "features") - variables work rather as you expect - BUT - signals are essentially designed for inter-process communication in a parallel processing system. If you think in C terms, the closest equivalent is a pipe opened on stdout and looped back into stdin! You can write to a pipe but nothing happens until you flush it...

In VHDL, the flush will only happen when the process suspends itself. As written, it cannot suspend itself until the loop ends and it reaches "`end process`". And it cannot end the loop until "`therm_int = 0`". And it cannot change the value seen on `therm_int` until it suspends ... this is an infinite loop.

To understand **why** VHDL signals work this way, see [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13954193/is-process-in-vhdl-reentrant/13956532#13956532)

The simplest way round this is to make `therm_int` another process variable and use variable assignment `:=` instead of signal assignment `<=` for it.

And now it should work.

4) Synthesis.

But what isn't synthesisable about it?

Only this: You used a `while` loop instead of a `for` loop!

Think about that for a moment: you cannot generally predict how many cycles a `while` loop will take. For synthesis, that means you have to generate an unknowable quantity of hardware!

But you could place an upper bound on the iterations, and generate hardware to cater for that upper bound. In fact a `for` loop is automatically bounded, and synthesis tools can handle that.

So write the loop as

```
therm_int := therm;
for j in therm_int'range loop  
   if therm_int /= 0 then
      therm_int := therm_int srl 1;
      i := i + 1;   
   end if;   
end loop;
```

and synthesise it.
Notes : `for j in therm_int'range loop`; why j? Well we don't want to hide your `i` variable! 
And note that `therm_int'range` automatically equates to `(6 downto 0)` or however you declared `therm_int`. This bombproofs your code against changes to the size of `therm_int` or accidental buffer overflows. It's one little example of what I meant by using the type system instead of fighting it.

While we're at it, let's eliminate the shift, which is unnecessary!

```
for j in therm_int'reverse_range loop  
   if therm_int (j) = '1' then
      i := j;   -- last assignment is most significant '1' bit
   end if;   
end loop;
```

As written, this will synthesise to generate enough hardware to implement the task in a single clock cycle. In general, that would lead to rather slow clock cycles, and you would want to ration the work (perhaps a single loop iteration per clock). But that's another story...

Comment: Sorry about taking so long to accept your answer; I forgot about this question and was recently reminded of it by the "popular question" badge.

Answer (score 1):

There are only seven possible outputs, or eight if you include 000, so there are only seven (eight) possible inputs. I would just use a lookup table, or a switch statement if you have one available.

Comment: I would use a lookup table if it were up to me. However, the purpose of the exercise is to "take advantage" of the fact that the golden-model need not be synthesizeable.

Comment: Also, removing a '0' from the while loop didn't do anything. It still doesn't compile

Comment: When you say "it doesn't compile", what error does it give? AFAIK, srl and sll are very much synthesizable. However, `i = i + 1;` isn't the correct syntax, I think it should be `i := i + 1:`

Comment: @StaceyAnne The `=` is indeed wrong. That is a relational operator (i.e. "is equals to"). But the way the OP has it, `i` is a port and so he would need the signal assignment operator `i <= i + 1;`. But as Brian Drummond points out, the OP probably wants `i` to be a variable. And so your usage of the variable assignment operator `:=` would be correct.

Comment: @embedded.kyle: you are quite correct;  an oversight on my part. I saw integer and thought variable.

Comment: @StaceyAnne It's weird how those patterns get ingrained in your brain after you've written enough in a particular language. We'll soon have the OP thinking just like you. :)

Comment: @embedded.kyle: I was actually thinking about this the other day,  how it really is all just patterns and combining various standard vhdl constructs that become so ingrained.  It's absolutely awesome when it gets to the point where you can see the waveform in your head as you write the code.

Comment: There are only 8 valid inputs, but your statement "There are only seven possible outputs, or eight if you include 000, so there are only seven (eight) possible inputs." isn't logical. There's lots of logic circuits with more inputs than outputs where all input combinations are valid. For example, any multiplexer.

Comment: @ThePhoton A ridiculous quibble. My answer applies to this question, not to the universe. Can we improve the signal-to-noise ratio please.

Comment: @EJP, sorry to quibble, but we are teaching people basic concepts here. Some readers are likely to read your answer to get a more general understanding of digital electronics. I felt it's better not to teach them the wrong way to reason about problems like this. If you don't wish to improve your answer, nobody will force you to.

Comment: @ThePhotion In what way did I 'teach' anybody the 'wrong way to reason'? And in what way could my answer be improved to overcome this perceived difficulty?